# While using multiple scanf() it skips the rest of the scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

When I enter a value for on of the `scanf()`

it just skips the second, third and any other `scanf()` right after it.

This is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float manyTest, gr1, gr2, gr3, gr4, gr5, gr6, gr7, gr8;
    manyTest = gr1 = gr2 = gr3 = gr4 = gr5 = gr6 = gr7 = gr8 = 0;

    printf("How many tests you wanna average? (Minimum 1 Maximum 8)\n");
    scanf(" %f", &manyTest);

    if (manyTest <= 0) {
        printf("The Minimum is 1!\n");    
    } else
    if (manyTest > 8) {
        printf("The Maximum is 8!\n");
    } else {
        if (manyTest = 1) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
        } else
        if (manyTest = 2) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
        } else
        if (manyTest = 3) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);    
        } else
        if (manyTest = 4) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
        } else
        if (manyTest = 5) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
        } else
        if (manyTest = 6) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
        } else
        if (manyTest = 7) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
        } else
        if (manyTest = 8) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
        }
        float avg = (gr1 + gr2 + gr3 + gr4 + gr5 + gr6 + gr7 + gr8) / manyTest;
        printf("Your average grade is: %.2f\n", avg);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

what is wrong with my code that it skips the rest of the `scanf()` ?
What I want the code to do is to ask how many tests they wanna average,
then to take that number (between 1 to 8) and put the tests of it, then it should average the grades.

lets say:

```
How many test...?
2
Write down your grades:
100
90
Your average grade is: 95.00
```

BUT, what it really does is:

```
How many test.....?
2
Write down your grades:
90
Your average is: 90.00
```

and doesn't even let it get info to the other variable.

Comment: Why is a space before `%f` in each of them ? Remove them .

Comment: Why not use an array and loops?

Comment: Also, you need to learn the difference between assignment (`=`) and comparison for equality (`==`).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes ,  in that case for input between `1` and `8` , first `if` will be executed and that `scanf` should work , if OP noted that or not.

Comment: I am not using array and loops because I haven't learn it yet. I am learning now new things and trying to practice them :)

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled (eg: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`).  This will prevent silly mistakes such as `=` / `==` confusion, which can happen to anyone as a typo.

Comment: You should use a loop.

Comment: No worries, take your time and you can learn step-by-step. =) But firstly, take that compiled-but-logically-error-line-thanks-to-C-standard element. :D

Comment: I removed the C++ tag, although it might compile as C++, your program is pure C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in your code, the culprit is not the `scanf` but these `wrong` equations

```
else if (manyTest = 8) //WROOOOONNGGGG!! =( =( =( =(
```

put double equal signs instead...

```
else if (manyTest == 8) //correct! =)
```

Because what you really want is comparison

Comment: Great. ;) glad to hear that. You might also want to learn about `array`, `for-loop` iteration, and `switch-case` block to make your code looks prettier.. ;) Not sure if it is what is required for you by your teacher now though...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the below statement will always match the first if.

First of all you need to use == to compare, because using = just makes this an assignment.

Secondly, the assignment `manyTest = 1` will always evaluate to true because that is how it works. So when you reach the `if (manyTest = 1)` the condition will be true so you will enter the first case which only has one scanf. You will never reach the other if-statements and test those conditions.

```
if (manyTest = 1) {
    printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
    scanf(" %f", &gr1);
}
else if (manyTest = 2) {
    printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
    scanf(" %f", &gr1);
    scanf(" %f", &gr2);
}
...
```

In the future when debugging something you can use different texts in printf in each if-statement to better understand where things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a classic bug in your code:

You use the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==` in your tests.  C is very flexible: it allows assignments in test expressions, which leads to the classic bug you run into. You have been bitten once, so now you know what you should type. Anybody can make a typo, there is a very efficient way to prevent the problem: compile with warnings enabled (eg: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`).